# Granting access to an additional directory to snaps

Tags: snap

How can I grant access to an additional directory (e.g not /home/user) to a snap package?
There is no slot available for directories other than `:desktop` and `:home` in `snap connections`.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to manually add a folder access. Snaps have their own home directory in ~/snap/

Comment: @JerareYoshi OK.So as far as I see , it's also not possible to add symlinks to other directories in the snap-specific areas.So perhaps the only way to achieve this is to embed all files and folders directly into it . What a ridiculous package manager !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind-mount additional directories into your home dir or into `~/snap/<snapname>/current` to be able to access them.

(snaps use apparmor to achieve the filesystem access confinement, apparmor does not deal with symlinks, but can handle bind mounts very well instead)

For more information on bind mounts, see [this answer on the Unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount).

Answer (score 1):

### 2023 update

It's possible today to manually manage snaps [connections](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management).

#### Examples

- Grand access to [removable medias](https://snapcraft.io/docs/removable-media-interface):

  ```
  snap connect [package_name]:removable-media
  ```

  Replace `[package_name]` with actual package name (example `fslint-unofficial`)
- Grand access to [home folder](https://snapcraft.io/docs/home-interface):

  ```
  snap connect [package_name]:home
  ```

  Replace `[package_name]` with actual package name (example `fslint-unofficial`)

Read https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-interfaces for complete interfaces list

#### Références

- https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management
- https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-interfaces